# How do I handle multiple pivot relationships in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my app, you can create lists of roles that are attached to contacts. So you can assign the contact "Bob" the roles of "Gardener" and "Pet Sitter". Then you can create the list "People" and add "Gardener (Bob)" and "Pet Sitter (Bob)" to it.

I have the following tables:

```
contacts
    id
    name
roles
    id
    name
contact_role (pivot)
    id
    contact_id
    role_id
lists
    id
    name
contact_role_list (pivot)
    id
    contact_role_id
    list_id
```

Everything was working smoothly until the second pivot table linked to the first pivot table. My pivot tables are (currently) not having any models so I'm not sure if there is a built-in feature to tackle this in Laravel or if I need to think differently.

I currently have this in my List model:

```
public function list_roles(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(XYZ::class, 'contact_role_list', 'list_id', 'contact_role_id');
}
```

Is this even close? What do I put where it says `XYZ::class`?

Comment: What is the relation between contact_role and list ? can a list have multiple contact_role or is it one on one ? Explain more the nature of the relation between those 3, contact, role and list.

Comment: @N69S I updated the post with explanation. A list can have multiple contact_role but it's unique on (contact_role_id,list_id) Thanks!

Comment: And a contact can have multiple roles and is unique on (contact_id, role_id)

Comment: have you checked if a hasManyThrough Relationship will help?[link]https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through 

Also is the relationship you are building on list just roles

i don't quite understand your model structure is this contacts can have many roles and roles can have many lists?

Comment: @JordanPartridge Thanks, I'm looking into hasManyThrough, although their example seem one step simpler than mine. Yes, contacts can have many roles and lists can have many contact_roles. There is no direct relationship between lists and roles, and no direct relationship between lists and contacts, they're both through contact_role.

Comment: I guess I could make it so my second pivot table (contact_role_list) has 3 foreign keys instead (contact_id, tag_id, list_id). I would avoid having to reference the contact_role table but it also seems a little redundant since I also need the contact_role table to keep track of the assigned roles.

Comment: I think what you should have is a  contact_roles pivot

and a  lists_roles pivots (laravel seems to prefer these are listed in Alphabetical Order

that should connect all your data then on your Contacts model you can build a lists relationship.

`public function lists() : hasManyThrough {
         return $this->hasManyThrough(List::class,  Role::class);
}`

In laravel simpler seems to be better there is usually a relationship built for every use case you just might need to rethink your approach a little

Comment: @JordanPartridge Thanks! I've looked into `hasManyThrough`, but in my `List` model I end up with something like `hasManyThrough(ContactRole::class, ContactRoleList::class, 'list_id', 'id', 'id', 'id')` and I still can't reach my `Contact` Model. I've also tried `belongsToMany(ContactRole::class, 'contact_role_list', 'event_id', 'contact_role_id')`.

Comment: I think I know too little about this to both understand what I need to do and how to explain it. I'll try to change my `contact_role_list ` to contain the two id fields from `contact_role` and bypass that whole relationship instead. Seems redundant, but would take a lot of the headache away.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the below is doing what I want, but is there an even better way to do it? The key to solving my problem was to create a Model for `ContactRole` and changing `extends Model` to `extends Pivot`.

I placed this in my `List` Model:

```
public function list_roles(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ContactRole::class, 'contact_role_list', 'list_id', 'contact_role_id');
}
```

And this in my `ContactRole` Model:

```
public function contact(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
}
```

Now I could reach the contact data by using something like this: `List::first()->contact_roles->first()->contact`

Any way to use `with`, `pivot` or similar to tidy this up even more? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to approach these issues in terms of Models rather than pivots. I think many new Developers in Laravel get over obsessed with what's going on in the Database which is fine, but theres a lot of Magic going on so you can write very simple code that does a lot of Heavy lifting, so that being said if I fully understand your problem

- You have a Contacts Model

  - This model can have many roles
    so in your contacts Model you need a role relationship

    ```
     public function roles() 
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Roles::class);
     }
    ```

next of course you have a role Model (pun intended)

your each role can have many list

```
public function lists()

    {
       return $this->hasMany(List::class)
    
    }
```

then the idea is now that you have roles on contacts and lists on roles you should be able to have many lists through contact

```
public function lists()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(List::class, Role::class);

}
```

I've done similar things before and for your description it seems like that's the approach you might need to take.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try it. It seems logical, but I’m still missing the linking tables (diving back into databases :P). Would your examples work out of the box with the table structure I mentioned with ’contact_role’ and ’contact_role_list’?

Comment: Assuming your last `lists()` was going in the `Contact` model: when I tinker `Contact::with('lists')->get();` I get Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.contact_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `lists`.*, `roles`.`contact_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `lists` inner join `roles` on `roles`.`id` = `lists`.`role_id` where `roles`.`contact_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))'